# Is it possible for a UK Citizen to apply for his non EU wife and child to come to Britain but apply from outside Britain?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, uk-visa, uk-citizens

I see only examples of applicants already living in Britain. My husband is planning on registering his British Citizenship (South African mother who was born in England) from within the US. Assuming he gets his citizenship, the question is how can we make a successful spouse/dependent application without breaking up our family (ie. he is living in Britain without us)? Is this possible and if so what is the process and would it be as likely to succeed as one done in the UK? Also, the applicant's occupation is Day Trader. Can that form of income count as work income? We would meet the work income level needed as a prerequisite for coming if so.. Thank you in advance for any thoughts, input, and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for applying are the same if you are outside the UK https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse

Being a day trader should be fine: it amounts to self employment. He will have records to show how he obtained his income legitimately.

If you can afford it you could employ a lawyer with UK immigration expertise to help you. It's not compulsory but it can save some stress.

It is not helpful to talk about *likelihood* of success: each application is assessed individually and if it meets the criteria it will be accepted.

The matter of breaking up the family: you may be thinking of people applying from low wage countries who don't earn the UK's required minimum income. They to go to the UK and get a job there to qualify, to then be allowed to bring their spouse. Often causing a separation of at least 6 months.